# C++ List of Objects code throwing std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I am writing the following a program and i get the std::bad_alloc exception.

```
class A{
public:
    int arr[5000];

    A() {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5000; i++ ) {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int cnt=0;
    std::list<A*> mylist;
    A *aref= NULL;
    for(int i=0;i<160000;i++){
        aref = new A();
        mylist.push_back(aref);
    }
}
```

I found that this error means i run out of memory. I would like to ask first if my List is stored in the heap then why i get this error. Second what is the heap max size?

I run same program in Java with -Xmx8000m and it terminates normally. My RAM is 16GB (if this matters)

Comment: Thank you! But my A Objects are not stored in the heap? How can i store my List in the heap

Comment: On what platform? With what compiler options? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: See update regarding heap storage with std::list

Comment: Thank you for your explicitly answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating 160000 of your `A`s with 5000 `int` in them, with usually around 4 bytes in size, so you are allocating 160000*5000*4 bytes, and which are /1024 = 3.125.000 kibiBytes and /1024 = 3.051,7578125 Mebibytes so around 3 GB, which is close to the upper limit, what a 32-bit process can get, and I assume, even when running x64 windows, you compiled it with the default x86 settings, meaning it will run with the 32bit compatibility mode in windows. Add the overhead of your 160000 pointers, which you stored in the most inefficient `std` container, plus overhead of paging `stuff, plus the likely added padding, and you get out of memory.

To get back to your original question:

1. The list is placed on the "stack" i.e. with automatic storage duration (more correct term), which means only the household data of it (for example a pointer to the first item, and one to the last and it's size), but not the items/nodes it contains, and even if it did, it does not contain the big stuff, i.e. your `A`s but simply pointers to them `A*`s, which in turn, as in any `std` container, except `std::array` are stored on the heap, i.e. "dynamic storage duration", but are nothing compared in size to the 5000 ints they point to. As you allocated with new, your `A` are never cleaned up until by a call with delete by you. C++ is very different from Java. And your Java code probably run as a 64bit process who knows what the VM did, as it saw that you wont use them in the future.

So if you want your `A`s on the "stack" i.e. automatic storage duration, you can use a `std::array<A,160000>` (which is a much better version of A[160000]), but I bet you will crash you stack with such sizes. (On most operating systems you get around 2MB of stack per Thread, but it can be much lower, and your call tree needs place too)

If you want your `A`s on the "heap" i.e. with dynamic storage duration, i.e. in the list, use `std::list<A>` instead of `std::list<A*>` and remove your `new` expression altogether. However because of multiple reasons, the best default container is `std::vector<A>` which would store them in one big chunk of "heap" memory.

2. There is no such explicit limit in the C++ standard, according to §3.7.4 of ISO/IEC 14882:2014, `new` either gets you the requested amount **or more**, or it fails, so it depends on your runtime i.e. implementation meaning operating system and compiler, but in general you can get as much as the operating system will give you, which as I said is around the 3-4GB for x86/32bit processes. Otherwise it can be much more, or in case of embedded applications, very less up to 0 (no dynamic allocation at all).

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` is implemented as a doubly linked list, with the nodes allocated on the heap. The `std::list<A*> mylist` object itself has automatic storage duration, it has a small `sizeof`, but each element you add with `mylist.push_back(aref)` to it will perform heap allocation in addition to the `new A` you do manually.